# Min/Max Question in two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can you please help me figure out how to prove/find all the min/max questions of the function $f(x,y)=cos(x+y)+x^2+y^2 $ inside $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ .

I was able to find $(0,0)$ as a critical point, but the Hessian in this point is zero and I have no idea how to check whether or not this is a maximum.

I am also pretty frustrated in trying to find max/min in the boundary using Lagrange multipliers.

Please notice that this is not a homework quetsion, but a pre-exam question...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey, did my solution answer your question? If not, I would be happy to make it more clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to locate all the extrema of
$$f(x,y)=\cos(x+y)+x^2+y^2$$
subject to
$$x^2+y^2\leq 1$$
First we set the partial derivatives to zero:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x-\sin(x+y) = 0$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y-\sin(x+y) = 0$$
This implies that $y=x$. Let's restrict our function to the line $y=x$.
$$f(x,y)|_{y=x} = f(x) = \cos(2x)+2x^2$$
Now let's see where this function has an extrema.
$$f'(x) = 0 = -2\sin(2x)+4x$$
Clearly this occurs at $x=0$. Next we check the second derivative.
$$f''(0) = -4\cos(2x)|_{x=0}+4= -4\cos(0)+4 = 0$$
I suspect this is partially what has been frustrating you. But never fear! All this means is that we must refer to the [higher-order derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_derivative_test). 
$$ \begin{align*}
\dfrac{d^3f}{dx^3}(0)= 8\sin{(2x)}|_{x=0} &=8\sin(0) = 0\\\
\dfrac{d^4f}{dx^4}(0)= 16\cos{(2x)}|_{x=0} &=16\cos(0) = 16
\end{align*}$$
Finally we can conclude that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is indeed a point of minimum value. Onto the absolute extrema! Since our function is continuous and achieves its only minimum on the interior, we need only check the exterior of the function. To do so we will use the Langrage method. That is, we must solve the following system of equations:
$$\begin{align*}
2x-\sin(x+y) &= 2\lambda x\\
2y-\sin(x+y) &= 2\lambda y\\
x^2 + y^2 &= 1
\end{align*}$$
Subtracting the first two equations yields $\lambda = 1$ or $x=y$. First, let $\lambda = 1$ Hence from the first equation,
$$\begin{align*}
2x-\sin(x+y) &= 2x\\
\iff \sin(x+y)&=0\\
\iff x+y&=\pi k &\text{ for some integer $k$}
\end{align*}$$
For any integer $k\neq0$, we violate the third equation. Hence, $k=0$. This yields the equality $x=-y$. Plugging this into the third equation gives us
$$\begin{align*}
2x^2 &= 1\\
x &= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}$$
We have thus located two critical points, $(x,y)=(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. You will note that these two points have the same image under $f$, and hence are both global extrema in the domain $x^2+y^2\leq 1$.

In conclusion, the function $f(x,y)=\cos(x+y)+x^2+y^2$ constrained to the domain $x^2+y^2\le 1$ achieves a relative minimum at $(0,0)$ and two absolute maxima at $(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Comment: Been a couple years since my multivariable calculus class, hope I didn't screw up somewhere!

Comment: On the line $x = y$, indeed $f$ has a minimum at $0$. But that doesn't rule out that $0$ is a saddle point, it could be that e.g. on the line $x = -y$, $f$ had a maximum at $0$. The point can be settled by Taylor, $\cos(x+y) + x^2 + y^2 = 1 - \frac{(x+y)^2}{2} + \frac{(x+y)^4}{4!} + x^2 + y^2 + O((x^2+y^2)^3) = 1 + \frac{(x-y)^2}{2} +\frac{(x+y)^4}{4!}+O((x^2+y^2)^3)$, thus $0$ is indeed a local minimum. Then, for the Lagrange multipliers, you get $\lambda = 1$ _or_ $x = y$ from the subtraction. $x = y$ gives you two minima at $\pm(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ on the boundary.

Comment: You took the higher-order derivatives only along the line $x = y$. That is sufficient here, but for $g(x,y) = \cos(x+y) + 2xy$, you'd similarly get $2y - \sin(x+y)$ and $2x - \sin(x+y)$ for the partial derivatives, so a critical point can also only lie on the line $x = y$. You get the same restriction along that line, but along the line $x = -y$, you'd get $h(t) = 1 - 2t^2$ which has a local maximum in $0$, hence $0$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Right, different problem but I appreciate you making the point. I may have missed it were that the proposed problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I couldn't understand your calculation with Taylor series... Can you please explain to me how did you get: $\cos(x+y) + x^2 + y^2 = 1 + \frac{(x-y)^2}{2} +\frac{(x+y)^4}{4!}+O((x^2+y^2)^3)$ Thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer: Upon second glance, I do not believe that the two minima you claim are true. Just plug them in, and you will see that those values map to $\cos(\sqrt{2}) + 1 > \cos(0)$. I stand by my original solution.

Comment: Consider $f$ restricted to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. It's continuous there, so assumes maxima and minima on the circle. Per Lagrange, you find that the critical points on the circle are $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}(1,1)$ and $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}(1,-1)$. For the former, the value is $\cos \sqrt{2} + 1 \approx 1.156$, for the latter, the value is $\cos 0 + 1 = 2$. So you have minima _on the boundary_ in $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}(1,1)$. It remains to check whether these are also (local) minima on the closed disk. Looking at the restriction of $f$ to the line $x = y$, you see that they aren't, but you need to check.

Comment: Regarding the Taylor expansion, $\cos z = 1 - z^2/2! + z^4/4! - z^6/6! + \ldots$. With $z = x+y$, the quadratic term becomes $-(x^2 + 2xy + y^2)/2$, adding $x^2 + y^2$ to that yields $(x^2 - 2xy + y^2)/2 = (x-y)^2/2$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you very much for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @Calculus2222 If you think this answer helped you, please consider [upvote it and accept it as an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer).